# At the present moment: Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm usually white,
>   but **right now** a striped one dominates me.
>
> For on this *day* I wear black,
>   and black is still my day.
>
> **At the present moment: Who am I?**

---

Clue 1:

> Related to sports

Clue 2:

> The time in which I created this puzzle is important

Clue 3:

> The Sport is: Futbol / Football / Soccer

Comment: I'm thinking you maybe able to word this better, unless its suppose it is like that for a reason...

Comment: @Daedric Can you give some clues? I learning English now, Maybe I can improve the question.

Comment: Its a bit hard to do exactly that as I would need to know exactly what your saying first, I'm a bit confused myself. How about: I am white right now, but one stripe dominates me. Today I wear black but it is still my day?

Comment: @Daedric the time is important here. I will check if I can improve the question with other words

Comment: Ok, just a suggestion, I like the question though it seems difficult.

Comment: @Daedric is not difficult, you will see

Comment: to the downvoter, I'm new in this site, if you can tell me why you vote down, I can improve my next question, thanks

Comment: @Daedric I add one clue

Comment: Where do you live? Is the "right now" connected to your local time? For now I see "14 hours ago", which for me is 21.25 of may 5th

Comment: @DamienPirsy not local time

Comment: Will the puzzle still be "valid" in future? If you need "the time at which the puzzle is written" it is not very suitable for this site... Also, if English is troublesome for you, "Riddle" might not be the best category to post, as several Riddles *rely* on not-accurate-phrasing. To differentiate between intension and error will be tricky - and people will generally not like it. Maybe you can have someone "check" your riddles before posting them?

Comment: @BmyGuest, yes the time still be valid, which tag will be the best? I edit with other clue

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, what I meant was: If you are not sure your English is correct - ask somebody (who knows the answer) to spell-check and correct it before posting. "Riddles" are often using incorrect language. Any "mistake" can therefore ruin the puzzle and make people here down-vote your puzzle.

Comment: @BmyGuest I need the time because is related to a event. Can be, really I leerning English at this moment, you can open a chat with me to talk about the question?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I'm still not sure, I found a football team with white and black stripes that played today: Juventus? Is this close?

Comment: Not now, sorry. (I'm in a hurry.)

Comment: @Daedric good for you, just found the other. And please, if you can help me to improve the question please

Comment: Wait is that it?

Comment: @Daedric you're in the right way, but the answer is not Juventus, read the news

Comment: Ok thought I was right for a moment, ill keep looking, and real madrid was who they played

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are:**

> **Real Madrid** (the football team)
>
>  Real Madrid players usually wear white jerseys,
>  but **today** they wore black playing against the striped team Juventus.
>  (**Juventus vs Real Madrid 5/5/2015**)

Comment: Today I wear black and likewise is still my day.? Who I am. You are close, and if you can explain why?

Comment: and you consider this as a bad puzzle? I'm discouraged with my English to make the puzzles correctly :-(

Comment: I didn't consider it bad, I upvoted!

Comment: Yes, but read the comments in the question. Can you finish the answer? And add some explanation?

Comment: Im not sure, still looking.

Comment: Is related to the color

Comment: Álvaro_Morata is it about this player?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a long-shot, but my answer is

> A skunk

I'm white, but right now!!! one striped dominates me

> a skunk's skin is white (well, pinkish)
>  a stereotypical skunk has one long stripe down its back

Today I wear black and likewise is still my day

> A skunk's fur is mostly black but for the white stripe
>  When people encounter a skunk they stay as still as possible.

Not sure it fits perfectly, but I tried.

Comment: the answer is other thing

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer:

> A turn 10 spare in bowling? Will elaborate if correct.

Comment: The sport is other, I will add other clue in minutes

Comment: I add other clue ;-) and god luck